# Swift 3 - Slider's pointer width

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I want to make a label for a slider that shows the position of the pointer like this:

[image]

This is my code that's moving this label when the slider's pointer moves:

```
var sliderPointWidth : CGFloat = 32.0

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged( _ slider : UISlider ){
    sliderLabel.text = "\( Int( roundf( slider.value ) ) )"
    let leftMove = slider.frame.minX
    let allRange = ( slider.frame.width - sliderPointWidth ) * CGFloat( slider.value / slider.maximumValue )
    let middleOfSliferLabel = sliderLabel.frame.width / 2
    let x = leftMove + sliderPointWidth / 2 + allRange - middleOfSliferLabel
    sliderLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint( x: CGFloat(x) , y: sliderLabel.frame.minY )
}
```

But to make the label's middle x and the pointer's middle x the same, I need to know the width of this pointer. Fluently looking in this, I understood that it's about 32 points. But I don't know this value for other screens. Are there any methods in `UISlider` that can say this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retreive the size for the thumb with `thumbRect`:

```
let thumbSize = slider.thumbRect(forBounds: slider.bounds, trackRect: slider.trackRect(forBounds: slider.bounds), value: 0).size
```